# Solr Search : SEVERE: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: solr, lucene

I am getting the following error when I try a search query in my solr, am not sure what might be causing this, but this has bought a halt to all our work.

This query works:

```
http://10.0.0.13:8080/solr/cmn/select/?q=*:*&fl=searchText&rows=40000
```

But this:

```
http://10.0.0.13:8080/solr/cmn/select/?q=solr
```

doesn't work, and gives the following exception:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.lucene.util.packed.Packed64.get(Packed64.java:186)
at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReaderIndex.seekEnum(TermInfosReaderIndex.java:118)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader.get(TermInfosReader.java:235)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader.get(TermInfosReader.java:172)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.docFreq(SegmentReader.java:509)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexReader.docFreq(SolrIndexReader.java:309)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight$1.add(TermQuery.java:56)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.ReaderUtil$Gather.run(ReaderUtil.java:77)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.ReaderUtil$Gather.run(ReaderUtil.java:82)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.ReaderUtil$Gather.run(ReaderUtil.java:66)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight.<init>(TermQuery.java:53)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery.createWeight(TermQuery.java:199)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.createNormalizedWeight(Searcher.java:168)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.createNormalizedWeight(IndexSearcher.java:664)
```

Regards,
Rohit

Comment: What version of Solr are you running ?

Comment: we are running solr version 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index had crashed due to improper shutdown of tomcat, though the error doesn't reflect the same, fixed the index using the following command,

```
java -cp ./example/work/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8983_solr.war__solr__k1kf17/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/lucene-core-3.1.0.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex "D:\Brandmanagement\solr\example\simplify360\crss\data\index" -fix
```

It would have been helpful if solr would have thrown the exact exception of the Index crashing. The index crashing issue has been fixed in solr 3.4 onward i guess.